# How to properly design a database, a single object vs multiple with relations

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project that will rely kinda heavily on a database, I've done several projects by now, but most of them barely had any significant database need, that would require me to put significant thought in it, but that time has come. I don't know much about databases, and I am not looking for someone to do it instead of me, but I am just looking for pointers and what to study/read in order to figure out how to handle the situation.

What the app will do is keep track of the items in stock (in the inventory) in a company, related to the products that it manufactures. I will have to be able to pull various kind of information, wether its all invoices, or all invoices related to a given product, or all items related to a given product, or all items for all products, and so on, you get the idea.

The basic structure that I have for now looks like this:

```
const inventory = {
  products: [
    {
      title: "",
      production: {
        finalized: 0,
        inProduction: 0,
      },
      items: [
        {
          title: "",
          price: {
            per: 0,
            total: 0,
          },
          quantity: {
            current: 0,
            type: "",
          },
          operations: {
            added: [
              {
                date: new Date(),
                quantity: 0,
                invoice: {
                  number: "",
                  supplier: "",
                },
              },
            ],
            removed: [
              {
                date: new Date(),
                quantity: 0,
                expenseId: "",
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

It is not complex at all, an array of products, and information about these products. Quantities, when a new quantity was added, when a quantity was taken, and so on.

The question is, do I make this with just 1 model for the whole inventory, which I am guessing will work, but will probably not be optimal.

Another approach that comes to mind is to make models for the items, invoices, products and so on, and then just have some logic that relates all of that within the inventory to get the structure that I have above. That performance wise will probably be better, because if I want to pull all invoices, I will just have to pull the invoices model instead of the whole inventory and loop through it to find my invoices.

What other options do I have?

I forgot to add that I will be using Mongoose, Express, React and Node.